# How to pass column names as parameters in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to be able to pass column names as parameters for fields references in jasper reports whenever executing query.

This is required so that .jrxml report will not be tied to column names listed in the query(effectively allowing to run any sql query on a jrxml report).

I want to do something like $F{$P!{Parameter1}} for value or category expressions in charts, where:

```
<parameter name="Parameter1" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["country"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

But I get error : "Field not found" get $P!{Parameter1 --- net.sj.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignExpression

Category data set(for chart):

```
<categoryDataset>
            <categorySeries>
                <seriesExpression><![CDATA[country]]></seriesExpression>
                <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{$P!{Parameter1}}]]></categoryExpression>
                <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{number_of_sites}]]></valueExpression>
            </categorySeries>
        </categoryDataset>
```

I am 100 % somebody attempted to do the same thing, any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, use parameter directly with default value which is column name in your case.

```
<categoryDataset>
     <categorySeries>
         <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$P!{Parameter1}]]></seriesExpression>
         <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$P!{Parameter1}]]></categoryExpression>
         <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{number_of_sites}]]></valueExpression>
     </categorySeries>
</categoryDataset>
```

Comment: tried that from the beginning: "$P cannot be resolved to variable". The trick here is that expected value is reference to $F field object not to the parameter. I've tried to use Variable as $V inside expressions and inside Variable give reference to $P but it again does not resolve the $P it substitutes $V with "$P{Parameter1} directly...

Answer (score 0):

I would try to manipulate the query (like dynamic sql) instead, using your parameter like you did within `categoryDataset`.

We used that many times to prepare our queries to retrieve the specified column for grouping purposes (mostly with jasperreports), and I'm pretty sure this will work for you, too.

Your query will look like this:

```
select
    column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    column4,
    $P!{Parameter1} as GROUP_COL

from
   yourTable
```

This is also covered in the [jasper docs](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/).

Comment: This would couple the query columns to some order. As you will imply fields will be represented as $P!{Parameter1} AS SERIES_EXPRESSION and say $P!{Parameter2} AS VALUE_EXPRESSION, so the queries firing against report must know in which order the columns must be supplied. In other words query should know to which general field name it must couple itself by using "AS" directive. We are already parsing jrxml because report unit is stupid and does not display parameters of its jrxml resource... More workarounds sounds worrying.

Answer (score -1):

you can not set variables in SQL as column or table names. But with the following trick you are able to.
I hope this will help you.

```
    DECLARE @variable1 system; /* type system is datatype for tablenames, columns etc.*/
    DECLARE @variable2 system;
    DECLARE @variable3 system;

    Select @variable1 = tablename, @variable2 = columname, @variable3 = variable
    From tempdb.dbo.powerdeviation
    Where ID = @ID

    /*please note that if the select result is giving you more then one result,
    the first row is used as the variable! There will be not error*/


    DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(max)='
    SELECT something
      FROM [db@variable1].[dbo].['+ @variable2 +']
      where LogInterval = 10 and PlantID = ''@variable3''
    '
    SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand,'@variable',@variable);
    SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand,'@variable2',@variable2);
    SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand,'@variable3',@variable3)

    PRINT @sqlCommand;
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sqlCommand;
```

Comment: With pure SQL ok, but with JasperReports you've got an abstraction layer in between. So to this question this seems not to be a correct answer.